# Unit testing a c# Method using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm new to unit testing and the language c sharp and I'm trying to unit test by mocking `ISessionStorageService` to test the `HasGlobaladminaccess`  function but my setup does not seem to work as expected.

```cs
public class Context
{
    public asyncTask<bool>HasGlobalAdminAccessAsync(Blazored.SessionStorage.ISessionStorageService sessionStorage)
    {
        return await HasAccessAsync(sessionStorage, Config.Constants.HAS_GLOBALE_ADMIN_ACCESS);
    }

    private async Task<bool> HasAccessAsync(Blazored.SessionStorage.ISessionStorageService sessionStorage, string sessionStorageKey)
    {
        ILogger _logger = Log.ForContext<ContextHelpers>();

        try
        {
            _logger.Debug("HasAccessAsync({sessionStorageKey})", sessionStorageKey);
            var access = await sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<bool>(sessionStorageKey);
            _logger.Debug("HasAccessAsync({sessionStorageKey})::access={access}", sessionStorageKey, access);
            return access;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Debug("HasAccessAsync({sessionStorageKey})::exception={ex}", sessionStorageKey, ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My test method

```cs
private readonly Mock<ISessionStorageService> MockStorage = new Mock<ISessionStorageService>();

[Fact()]
public async Task HasGlobalAdminAccessAsyncTest()
{
    string guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Context context = new Context();
    MockStorage.Setup(foo => foo.GetItemAsync<bool>(guid)).ReturnsAsync(true);
    var person = await context.HasGlobalAdminAccessAsync(MockStorage.Object);
    Assert.True(person , guid);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to test with this line: `Assert.True(person, guid)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Either use the same value as what's in `Config.Constants.HAS_GLOBALE_ADMIN_ACCESS` for the GUID value in your test

Or use

```
foo => foo.GetItemAsync<bool>(It.IsAny<Guid>())
```

In your `Setup` call.

As it's written, you have your test set to only accept the exact GUID that is returned from `Guid.NewGuid()` in your test, so it's not going to work in general.